# Select Distinct values once from multiple columns in this table preserving original order?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a (subquery) table that lists meal preferences for my friends. Each meal can only be taken once, and each person can only eat one meal.

```
row_number person_id   meal_id
   1           1           3       
   2           2           1
   3           2           2
   4           2           3      
   5           3           1   
   6           3           2
   7           3           3
```

The picking order is determined by the original order of the table, so I would like the result to be:

```
person_id   meal_id
   1           3       
   2           1   
   3           2
```

Because meal 1 is taken by user 2, user 3 gets meal 2. I think this could be solved by selecting distinct values in both columns based on their original order, but I cannot figure out how to write that query. Any help appreciated.

**Update** Added `row_number` to original table.

Comment: There simply is no guarantee whatsoever that you can reproduce "the original order" because tables are "un-ordered". To guarantee any order in a result using SQL you must use an `order by` clause. So, is there ANYTHING else in that table to assist in reproducing the desired order? e.g. a timestamp? an ID?

Comment: Thanks @Used_By_Already. The table comes from a subquery, but I can use `row_number()` to create a sequential order. I updated the example if you want to take a look.

Comment: You want each person to get a different meal? What if there are not enough meals or all meals a person prefers are already assigned?

Comment: @dnoeth You can just assume that this will never happen, as I will handle this when inputting the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this is a rather complicated graph walking problem.  I should first note that there is no guarantee of an optimal solution -- without lots and lots of work.  But you can implement a greedy algorithm using recursive CTEs:

```
with recursive t as (
      select v.*
      from (values (1, 1, 3), (2, 2, 1), (3, 2, 2), (4, 2, 3), (5, 3, 1), (6, 3, 2), (7, 3, 3)
           ) v(row_number, person_id, meal_id)
     ),
     cte (row_number, person_id, meal_id, rows, persons, meals, lev) as (
     select row_number, person_id, meal_id, array[row_number], array[person_id], array[meal_id], 1 as lev
     from t
     where row_number = 1
     union all
     select t.row_number, t.person_id, t.meal_id,
            (case when t.person_id = any(cte.persons) or t.meal_id = any(cte.meals)
                  then cte.rows
                  else array_append(cte.rows, t.row_number)
             end),
            (case when t.person_id = any(cte.persons) or t.meal_id = any(cte.meals)
                  then cte.persons
                  else array_append(cte.persons, t.person_id)
             end),
            (case when t.person_id = any(cte.persons) or t.meal_id = any(cte.meals)
                  then cte.meals
                  else array_append(cte.meals, t.meal_id)
             end),
            cte.lev + 1
     from cte join
          t
          on t.row_number = cte.row_number + 1
    )
select t.*
from t cross join
     (select rows from cte order by lev desc fetch first 1 row only) as last1
where t.row_number = any (last1.rows);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=f7aa7ca1498cac67adea1b9d372a6c23) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thank you! I might rethink my DB schema after seeing this. This is a huge help.

Comment: yep: I would encourage you to re-think that schema.